# Drupal 7 Webform 4.0 default value from URL

Tags: url, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal 7 and Webform 4. I am trying to retrieve value from URL and want to assign it to my text box as default value. Basically, its a carrer application page from which I want users to apply for specific job only.

So, I have assigned default value as [current-page:query:job].

And then I tried using URL localhost/carrer?job=121, But value is not getting populated in Textbox. Please help as I am not able to find any documentation for syntax of this.

Comment: Is the token module enabled?

Comment: Thank you a lot progzy for your question. The Token module was the missing. As the basic token API is now a part of Drupal 7, I assumed(never assume lesson learnt!!!) the current-page is also part of basic feature. If some one similar lands up here, please note that you need Token module for it.

Comment: I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the token module is the fix

Comment: @progzy Please do not put smiley faces `:)` in your comments/answers. Please keep it clean and professional, this is not a social site. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255732/1153362).

Comment: @PedroOliveira that is what I did. Please read comments carefuly before criticizing.

Comment: @Substantial acknowledged